# getting the data of a row of a table of an html page using powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I need to get the data of a row of a table of an html page using powershell. The code snippet I have tried is this.

```
foreach($table in $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")) {

foreach($tr in $table.getElementsByTagName("tr")) {


        $trval=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")|?{$_.innerText -eq '2 - High' }
        if($trval -eq $true)
{
foreach($td in $tr.getElementsByTagName("td")) {
 $htmlResults += $td.geElementsByValue 

}
```

I need to get the datails of all rows in a table with column name '2-High' into an array. How can I do this using powershell

Comment: Have you looked at using the HTML Agility Pack to do this kind of web scraping? [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) You can load the assembly in PowerShell and use it as seen [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/how-to-import-data-from-html-pages/)

Comment: Can you explain it in detail